# Subscript in text (Windows Forms) in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

How to display superscript in Windows Forms using C#. 
Say, i need to display 5 cubic metre as 
    5 m3 (with 3 as superscript).

Answer (score 2):

The keystroke for the '³' character is Alt+0179. Charmap is your friend. ;)